# how to create FoxPro dbf files from c++?

Tags: c++, database, foxpro

I need to read a FoxPro Dbf File and recreate same in c++; I installed foxpro driver version 9.0 but it did not appeared in driver list in windows DSN. I then installed foxpro from visual studio 6 setup and that showed the driver there and I was able to make connection using it through ADO .Problem is that

```
    _ConnectionPtr m_pCon;
   _RecordsetPtr m_pRecordset;
   AfxOleInit();
_bstr_t bt1(PassedCstringDirectory);//PassedCstringDirectory passed as argument
 _bstr_t bt(sqlcmd);//sqlcmd passed as argument
   m_pCon.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
    HRESULT hr;
 VARIANT *rowseffected=NULL;
   try
   {
      //The SourceDB should be a proper directory
      hr=m_pCon->Open("Provider=VFPOLEDB; SourceType=DBF; "
                      "SourceDB="+bt1+";Extended Properties=FoxPro 3.0;", "","",adModeUnknown); 
   }
   catch(_com_error e)
   {
      AfxMessageBox("Connection failed, check the direction!");
   } 
   m_pCon->Execute(bt,rowseffected,adConnectUnspecified);
```

m_pCon->Execute() is returning false(S_FALSE) but files (dbf and fpt) are being created .and i am not able to insert data into files .error being ."Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype."

Comment: Use connection string from here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro/

Comment: @Oleg i tried that to see same result.

Comment: Try to use this provider: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839

Comment: @Oleg earlier i used the provider u mentioned but it was not even shown in driver list .It did not even opened connection .After that i installed fox pro from vb6.

Comment: For creating the table, we are not seeing the "SQLCmd" that was passed in as the argument.  If you had a valid connection, then it might just have been syntax of the command you tried to execute.